# How to convert full date character into mm/dd/yyyy in R?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a dataset in R with a date column that is currently being treated as a character column. The dates in this column are listed as "August 24 2012" and I am trying to convert it into a date format such as 08/24/2012.

I am a novice with R and have tried to use format() and lubridate with no success. How do I convert these dates from a character to date?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We need to convert it to `Date` class and then use `format`

```
format(as.Date(dates, "%B %d %Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "08/24/2012"
```

As the order is month, day, year use `mdy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
format(mdy(dates), "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "08/24/2012"
```

It is based on the order, e.g.

```
ydm("2012 24 August")
#[1] "2012-08-24"
```

#### data

```
dates <- "August 24 2012"
```